# Conditional memcached usage in isomorphic application

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, memcached, isomorphic-javascript

1. I have isomorphic application that depend on package with class that implement api of microservice.
2. I have package that implement api of microservice and extend other class — basic class to all my microservice packages and this class live in another package.
3. I have package with basic class which implement requests to microservices etc.

I want to implement caching with memcached for server side requests to api. So I add it to basic class of all microserice classes.
I try to use conditional require for memcached like this:

```
this.cache =
  process &&
  process.env &&
  process.env.CACHE_CONFIG &&
  Object.key(process.env.CACHE_CONFIG).length > 0;

if (this.cache === true) {
  const Memcached = require('memcached'); // eslint-disable-line
  const uri = process.env.CACHE_SERVER || '127.0.0.1:11211';
  this.memcached = new Memcached(uri);
}
```

But it fails:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/memcached/lib/connection.js Module not found:
>
> Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/memcached/lib/memcached.js Module not found:
>
> Error: Can't resolve 'net'

How I may fix this? Any ideas?

With all my best Regards.

**UPDATE**
I have add this to webpack config:

```
  node: {
    net: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
```

build was successful. now — testing.